# ハングアウトチャットを利用したBot作成

Tags: google-apps-script

チャットルームのなかにBotを追加して社内の共有ドライブやマイドライブ内のファイルを掲示できるようにしたいのですが可能でしょうか？もしあればやり方やgasのコード等のご教示いただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: やり方やGASのコード提示するにはまだ要件があいまいな印象です。でもう少し具体的なワークフローを提示していただくと回答が付きやすいと思います

Comment: コード作成依頼や一からコードを教えてほしい系の質問は回答が付きづらいです。これまでに実施したコード等があると、より回答が得られやすいでしょう。